# Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be such that $f_1(z)=\sin(z)$, and $f_{n+1}(z)=\sin(f_n(z))$. Show $\{f_n\}$ is not locally bounded near the origin.

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be the sequence of iterates of the sine function: namely, $f_1(z)=\sin(z)$, and $f_{n+1}(z)=\sin(f_n(z))$ when $n\geq 1$. Show that this sequence $\{f_n\}$ is not locally bounded in any neighborhood of the origin.

I'm having trouble with this. This is my attempt:

Suppose to the contrary that $\{f_n\}$ is locally bounded on some $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,|z|<\varepsilon\}$. Then Montel's theorem shows that there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ converging to some holomorphic $f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $D$. Since $f(0)=0$ we can choose (through continuity) $\varepsilon$ small enough that $f(D)\subseteq\mathbb{D}$. Now (I think) f'(0)=1$... something something something sine behaves weirdly causing a contradiction.

Is Schwarz' lemma applicable here? I feel like I'm close but I have a few technical details I need to work out. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple different possible approaches to the problem.

1. If $f_{n_k}$ converges to $f$ uniformly, then the derivatives $f^{(m)}_{n_k}$ must converge uniformly to $f^{(m)}$ as well.  Try computing $f_n^{(m)}(0)$ for different small values of $m$ until you can find a contradiction.
2. If $x$ is small and real, how does $\sin(x)$ compare to $x$?  What does this tell you about the behavior of $f_n(x)$ as $n\to\infty$?  If $f_{n_k}$ converges uniformly to $f$, what does this tell you about $f$?  Now compute $f'(0)$ as suggested above to get a contradiction.

Comment: So I've noticed that $f'''_n(0)=-n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (which can be proved by induction), so $\{f'''_n\}$ is not locally bounded and so cannot be a normal family by Montel's theorem. If $\{f_n\}$ is a normal family then $\{f'''_n\}$ would be as well, which is a contradiction. Right?

For the second point you raised, I've determined that $f_n(z)\simeq z$ in a small enough neighborhood, and so $f'(0)=1$, but I don't quite see how that helps me so much?

Comment: If $x$ is a small positive real, is $\sin(x)$ bigger than or smaller than $x$?  What about $\sin(\sin(x))$?

Comment: Thank you! So in a neighborhood of $x$, $\sin(x)<x$, which implies $\sin(\sin(x))<\sin(x)$, etc... and since $f_n(0)=0$, $f(x)=0$, which would contradict $f(0)=1$. Correct?